# Basic MVC structure problems

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I want to implement the Model-View-Controller pattern as described at this image:
[image]

For one view, one model, and one controller I understand it very well.
But how to do it with more than one of each?

For example:
If I have a view, which consists of many different partial view.
And each of this partial views have one model and one controller.
Okay, fine.
But if one partial view wants to execute a command on it's controller, what depends on the data from another view: How do they communicate?

Comment: Work with the concept that a "view" could be a controller for multiple sub views or, that the parent view becomes a coordinator for multiple controllers (and their views)

Answer (score 0):

Usually each view keeps a reference to what it is observing. So a partial view can query the model for the other view. Controllers for a GUI seem to have their "controller code" sprinkled around in the GUI. You might also consider the [mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).